# Rails text fields for form_helper, how do I get a hash in hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsley.js

I'm trying to integrate ParsleyJS with Rails. The problem is that I can't seem to make a "hash in a hash"

```
  <%= f.email_field :email ,
      class: "form-control",
      parsley: { type: "email", trigger: "keyup"},
      placeholder: "Email-Address" %>
```

O end up with something like this: `parsley="{:type=>"email", :trigger=>"keyup"}"` in the HTML. For `data` such as `data: { toggle: 'tooltip', original_title: 'thingie'}`, these are parsed into `data-toggle="tooltip"`.

This works:

```
parsley: { type: "email"} # It gets parsed to parsley-type
```

But I can't have two or more attributes. What gives?

Comment: I always thought doing that with :data was special, "data tags". But you can just do "parsley-type" => "email", "parsley-trigger" => "keyup" to still get what you want.

Comment: Thanks @MrDanA, I guess there is no work-around unless I change the function itself?